# Parser Error: Expected "," or ")" after a "signal" parameter identifier

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

The Player Script giving me the error.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const FRICTION = 5000
const ACCELERATION = 5000
const MOVE_SPEED = 300

onready var animationPlayer = $AnimationPlayer

var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var aim_direction: Vector2
var max_recoil: float
var current_recoil: float

# Declare the signal that will be used to add recoil to the player's aim
signal add_recoil(recoil: float)

func _ready():
    aim_direction = Vector2(1, 0)
    max_recoil = 20
    current_recoil = 0
    connect("add_recoil", self, "_on_add_recoil")

# Add recoil to the player's aim
func _on_add_recoil(recoil: float) -> void:
    current_recoil += recoil
    
    # Clamp the current recoil to the maximum recoil
    current_recoil = clamp(current_recoil, 0, max_recoil)


func _physics_process(delta):
    #--Local Variables--
    var lerp_rate = FRICTION

    #--Input Logic--
    var input_vector = Vector2(Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left"),
                       Input.get_action_strength("ui_down") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_up"))
    if input_vector.y != 0: lerp_rate = ACCELERATION

    #--Animation Logic--
    if input_vector.y == -1:
        animationPlayer.play("WalkUp")
    elif input_vector.y == 1:
        animationPlayer.play("WalkDown")
    elif input_vector == Vector2.ZERO:
        animationPlayer.stop()

    #--Movement--
    velocity = velocity.move_toward(MOVE_SPEED*input_vector, lerp_rate*delta) 
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    
    # Slowly reduce the current recoil over time
    current_recoil = lerp(current_recoil, 0, delta * 5)
    
    # Rotate the aim direction by the current recoil
    aim_direction = aim_direction.rotated(current_recoil)
```

The error is coming up on *signal add_recoil(recoil: float)*
It'll be great if any coding wises for the Godot engine could explain how to fix this.

It's supposed to receive the signal from the WeaponBaseClass script to the players aim.

The script in question:

```
extends KinematicBody2D
export (PackedScene) var Bullet

# Declare variables to store the properties of the weapon
export var weapon_name: String
export var recoil: float
export var damage: int
export var shooting_speed: float
export var magazine_capacity: int
export var reload_speed: float
export var attachments: Array

# Get a reference to the player kinematic node in the main scene
onready var player_node = get_node("/root/Main/Player")

# Declare a variable to store the speed of the bullets fired by the weapon
export var bullet_speed: float

onready var end_of_gun = $EndOfGun

# Declare variables to store the current state of the weapon
var current_magazine: int
var is_reloading: bool

# Initialize the weapon
func _ready():
    current_magazine = magazine_capacity
    is_reloading = false

func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())

func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event.is_action_released ("shoot"):
        shoot()
    if event.is_action_released ("reload"):
        reload()

# Shoot the weapon
func shoot():
    # Check if the weapon is reloading or out of ammo
    if is_reloading or current_magazine <= 0:
        return
    
    # Decrement the magazine size
    current_magazine -= 1
    
    # Emit the "add_recoil" signal to tell the player to add recoil to their aim
    EventBus.emit_signal("add_recoil", recoil)
    
    # Send the add_recoil signal to the player
    player_node.add_recoil(recoil)
    
    # Play a shooting sound effect
    #audio_play("shoot.wav")
    
    # Spawn a bullet and apply damage to any enemies it hits
    var bullet = preload("Bullet.tscn").instance()
    
    # Set the bullet speed
    #bullet.set_linear_velocity(Vector2(BULLET_SPEED, 0))
    
    var target = get_global_mouse_position()
    var direction_to_mouse = end_of_gun.global_position.direction_to(target).normalized()
    bullet.rotation = get_global_transform().get_rotation()
    EventBus.emit_signal("fired_bullet", bullet, end_of_gun.global_position, direction_to_mouse)
    bullet.damage = damage
    add_child(bullet)

# Reload the weapon
func reload():
    # Check if the weapon is already reloading
    if is_reloading:
        return
    
    # Set the reloading flag
    is_reloading = true
    
    # Play a reloading sound effect
    #audio_play("reload.wav")
    
    # Call the reload animation
    $AnimationPlayer.play("reload")
    
    # Wait for the reload time to elapse
    yield(get_tree().create_timer(reload_speed), "timeout")
    
    # Reset the reloading flag and refill the magazine
    is_reloading = false
    current_magazine = magazine_capacity
```

I also have an EventBus script if that helps:

```
extends Node

#Only holds signals
signal fired_bullet(bullet, position, direction)
```

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/26045)

Answer (score 2):

GDScript in Godot 3 does not support specifying types for signal parameters. *It would work in Godot 4.*

So Godot 3 won't parse this:

```
signal add_recoil(recoil: float)
```

Instead you would have to drop the type:

```
signal add_recoil(recoil)
```